# How can I call bind on a computation expression without the let keyword?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

Say I have this:

```
MyComputationExpression {
    let! addr = Salesrecord.Address
    let! name = Salesrecord.Name
    return (name + " " + addr)
}
```

Is there any way to "unwrap" (call the `bind` method on) the address and name on the fly? Sort of like:

```
MyComputationExpression {
    (Salesrecord.Name! + " " + Salesrecord.Address!)
}
```

(If ! was the operator for unwrap on the fly). It seems a bit verbose to have to declare a new variable every time I want to use the result of `bind` just once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Bind` and `Return` methods are available on `MyComputationExpression`. Your original code is converted to this equivalent code:

```
MyComputationExpression.Bind(
    Salesrecord.Address,
    fun addr -> MyComputationExpression.Bind(
        Salesrecord.Name,
        fun name -> async.Return (name + " " + addr)))
```

This is quite ugly code, which is why computation expressions exist as a language feature. Being able to use them inline in the way that you want is currently not possible. It would be an additional language feature and [it has been suggested before](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/374).

Answer (score 2):

Your specific example may be easily called from an operator, in order to be inlined:

```
let inline (+?) a b =
    MyComputationExpression(){
        let! x = a
        let! y = b
        return x + y }

Some 3 +? None
salesrecord.Address +? Some " " +? salesrecord.Name
```

In more complicated cases, the need to explicity execute `bind` on the remainder of the computation may at least improve readability.